# password form before closing or minimizing app

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, passwords, formclosing

Im not sure if there is something like this in stackoverlow but what I found was password protecting the code, password protect before using the app. What if I want password before closing/minimizing?

Based on this article [Password before opening](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/display-a-simple-password-dialog-before-a-program-starts-in-c/)

What I did was Main form on load I create the password.txt which contains the password and on form closing I’ve put the code:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        pWd frm = new pWd();
        if (frm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {

            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

On the pWd form which is the password form I've put the code:

```
internal void btn_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // read file content into a string
        String fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"password.txt");`

        // compare TextBox content with file content
        if (fileContent.Equals(txt_pwd.Text))
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password");
        }
    }
```

But of course, you might have guessed already what will happen, it will just loop because the code is on the form_closing of main form. The second time I input password, it will throw exception. How do I do this properly?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: what exeption is thrown the second time you input password ?

Comment: why do you have Application.Exit() in the FormClosing event of your main form? If the pass is correct then the application will close you need no code for that

Comment: Hi @GuidoG,  Thank you for your answer... Perfect! How do I make your comment the Answer?

Comment: you can edit your question and write there what solved your issue

Comment: One last thing @GuidoG, how do I apply this code to minimize and Restore? I tried to find the events but I think I don't know where to find it. Thanks in advance.